# Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::filter()

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Please I need quick help. Am trying to import a large excel file in chunk using this code as per the documentation:

```php
Excel::filter('chunk')
    ->load('file.csv')
    ->chunk(250, function($results)
    {
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    });
```

However, I am getting this error which I can't understand.

> Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::filter()

I have checked everywhere online and can't find the same error anywhere. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please, implement the interface `WithChunkReading`. And return the chunkSize (in bytes) from the method named `chunkSize`. For example:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithChunkReading
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name' => $row[0],
        ]);
    }
    
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

And call the import method like below from your controller method:

```
return Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');
```

N.B: This should work from the laravel-excel version 3.1

Comment: Thanks for the response. But am failing to implement the above. How do i call it in my code? Initially I was using  this Excel::toArray($request->file('file_upload'), $path); but later it failed for bigger files thats when I landed on the filter function when I wanted to implement chunks. Now my controller has many other functions, do i need to create a new controller to handle only this or ?

Comment: You may build the array or collection data on your existing controller method. Then you may pass that data to the class which is used to import your data using constructor method. After that you have data on your `UsersImport` class. Then return the array from the `model()` method just. It should work. After building data from your controller, return the `return Excel::import(new UsersImport, 'users.xlsx');` line from your controller method.

Comment: Oh ok, let me try that. Thanks alot.

Comment: If, it solves your issue, then please hit an up-vote to the answer for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to disturb but I never got to finish this. Got busy with other work and put it on hold. One more question, is the usersImport class a model or controller? Secondly, is it standard that i have to call it usersImport or I can use any other name? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the `Excel::filter('chunk')` is removed in version 3.1 See the changelog [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html#upgrading-to-3-1-from-3-0):

> Excel::filter('chunk') method is removed, chunk filter is automatically added when using chunk reading.

Also `Excel::load()` is removed. So you can use `Excel::import(..)`, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I had no idea about this,